# Can't find webpage on All Pages or All Post menus

Tags: posts, pages

There is a page on my wordpress site, let's say http://hostname.com/our-philosophy/ (even Google is indexing it) that I want to delete.

However I cannot find it on the "All Pages" menu, or in the "All posts" menu so I don't know what to do about it. It has the looks of a blog post with a link referenced to itself... Any suggestions?

Comment: Could be a post type, term or taxonomy archive; might be created by one of your plugins - many possibilities.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a default theme and deactivating plugins? If it disappears, you can then turn them back on one by one to determine where it's coming from.

Comment: You may even want to check on the server, in case the folder ("our-philosophy") actually exists and contains a page.

Comment: Our-philosophy is not a folder in public-html/

Comment: I did create another page titled with the same name and the permalink saves as /our-philosophy-2/ so there is a missing link in some table. I barely have plugins, just Gutenberg (arrrg) and TablePress, so not their fault

Comment: Look in the trash, you could just the trash of both posts and pages

Comment: Trash is (are) empty..

Comment: OH WAIT, it is the permalink created by a PDF in the media. So, our-philosophy.pdf is creating that empty webpage...

Comment: if you have this question again, try the plugin Query Monitor, it helps to find which template is used https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

A PDF file contained in the Media and with the same name, created this empty webpage that somehow was indexed by google